# Balance weight beam reading

Tags: gravity

If there are two balance beam scales with one placed directly on the hard surface of  a floor and the other placed on a thick spongy carpet in between it and the floor, will they both indicate the same weight if you place a 100 pound weight on each, or, would the spongy surface absorb some of the weight?

Answer (score 1):

If you stand on any surface, be it a piece of steel, concrete, wood, or foam, it gives a little until it pushes back against your weight with the same force. That is still true even if there is a scale between you and the surface. You stand on the scale; you and the scale (under the force of gravity) push down on the surface underneath until that surface pushes back against you and the scale with the same force.

Answer (score 0):

they will both read the same. the material under the scale has no influence on the weight being measured.